# Build failed when attempting to launch react native project via Android Studio

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to run my react native project in Android Studio via the **Emulator** but the following error appears when attempting to run the project:

`FAILURE: Build failed with an exception`

- What went wrong:
  `Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'`.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'

I followed the steps for setting up the development environment, https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.

I added `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m` to the `gradle.properties` as advised from another fix but it is still not running.

The project runs perfectly on *iOS*, *Xcode* but not for ***Android***.

I am using 'compileSdkVersion = 31` in the /android/build.gradle file.

Can someone please help here?

Comment: It seems that some files duplicate. Try to clean up previous build `cd android && ./gradlew clean`

Comment: Thanks. I used your command to clean up but still got the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Have you checked if 2 native libraries registered the same modules 2 times. Try to trace back to when this issue occurred and make sure if you didn't install new library which conflicting with existing ones

Comment: Sorry, but I'm very new to react native and Android studio. How do I check if the native libraries registered the same modules? How would I trace back? I'm not sure if I installed new libraries that conflict with existing. Can you help at all on how I can go about checking this? Thanks

Comment: Can someone please help? I’m new to Android studio and react native